# troubleshoot display SharePoint columns from Infopath calculated fields

Tags: sharepoint

I have/had a problem with field values from existing InfoPath forms not displaying in Sharepoint form library columns (columns are checked as visible). I fixed the error which was caused by a mis-calculation in the errant field/column.  The form fields value now appears but only in a newly created form, the old forms corrected value does not appear after the fix.

Is there a way to re-calculate or refresh the old forms so they recognize the correct values and display them correctly in the SharePoint column?  I have a form library with hundreds of forms that I would like to get this one particular column to display correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to open each of the old existing forms and save it again (i.e. refresh) the form so it recalculates the values, then the new values will be displayed in its corresponding column in the form library.  Tedious job, but it works!